# Composition of sequences and solving sequences limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm studying calculus 1, and it came to my mind that there aren't any theorems about limits of composition of sequences. That's because we cannot define something like a composition of sequence, right? Because a sequence $\{ a_n \}$ is defined always from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, if we had something like $\{ a_n \} \circ \{ b_n \}$ could never exist because the image/codomain of $\{ a_n \}$ would never$^1$ be equal to $\mathbb{N}$, right?

Also, that means that, for sequences, we do not have an equivalent of theorems like, given three real functions $f, g, h$ with $f \sim h$ for a $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ for a neighborhood in which all three functions are defined:

- $f(g(x)) \sim h(g(x))$
- $log(f(x)) \sim log(h(x))$ (if $lim_{x->x_0}(g) \neq 1$)

or like the theorem of the limit of two composit functions (not necesarily continuos, as that's obvious it's not the case of sequences), correct?

- $\sim$ indicates the ["asymptotic relation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition)

$^1$ for "never" I mean regarding stuff that usually occours in a limit of a sequence in a calculus 1 course. There are some particular cases where the image of a sequence is just $\mathbb{N}$ or its subset, for example $ \{ a_n \}:= n+1$

Comment: What does $f\sim h$ mean?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks, added the meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in most cases. However, when $(c_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of *natural* numbers, then you can consider the sequence $\left(a_{c_n}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$, in which case you can recover statements of the sort of those that you mentioned. For instance:

- If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=l$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=\infty$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{c_n}=l$.
- If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=\infty$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{c_n}}{b_{c_n}}=1$.

Comment: thanks, interesting also that it has to be  $c_n -> \infty$, didn't thought about it at first but it's an obvious consequence of the nature of sequences

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Sorry, one question came to my mind: when you say "when $(c_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is a sequence of natural numbers", you mean that $c_n \in \mathbb{N}$ right? Otherwise, if $a_n$ would have a non-natural input, it wouldn't be a sequence, right? I say this because I saw the statement that, because $ (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n -> e$, then we can say that, as long as $a_n -> \pm \infty$ (no restriction on its output being in $\mathbb{N}$) also $ (1+ \frac{1}{a_n})^{a_n} -> e$.

Comment: So, after seeing that statement, it came to my mind that my "output $\in \mathbb{N}$" reasoning might be wrong, and the reason for that might have been that we're  not really "composing" two sequences when substituting $n$ with a sequence, in another sequence, but we're doing something else that works for some other reason.

Comment: A sequence of natural numbers is a sequence such that each of its terms is a natural number, yes.

Comment: ok thanks, so $(1+\frac{1}{a_n})^{a_n} \to e$ is just a particular "lucky" case right?

Comment: The fact that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{a_n}\right)^{a_n}=e$$is a consequence of the fact that$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=\infty.$$

Comment: ok thanks (i guess it's a typo, should be $e$ instead of $\infty$ in the last limit)

Comment: Yes, I meant $e$.